# The Historical Influence of Philosophy on Popular Thought: Did Early Feminism Draw Inspiration from Feminist Philosophy?

Tags: feminism

I've been pondering the relationship between philosophy and popular thought, specifically in the context of early feminist movements. It's fascinating to explore how ideas developed within the realm of philosophy have influenced and shaped popular thinking throughout history. More specifically, I'm curious about the connection between feminist philosophy and the emergence of early feminism.

Comment: How many words end in "tion"? You may, *cogito*, find the answer in that list. Good luck!

Comment: Seems a pretty vague & open-ended question, to which the trite summary is, of course they did. Eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Wollstonecraft#legacy

Comment: IMO Feminist philosophy is quite recent: maybe the influence is in the other direction.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Much depends here on how you define "philosophy" and "feminism". Mary Wollstonecraft is certainly regarded as the first feminist philosopher. Political, cultural and social changes happened alongside the philosophy. How far it caused or reflected them is another question; most likely the philosophy developed as part of the wider changes.